# tcpdf certification by.. is invalid

Tags: tcpdf

I followed the steps indicated in Example 052 (https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_052/) for generating a pdf with digital signature using tcpdf with a self signed crt. I read also that part about adding the pdf to Adobe List of Trusted Identities. For testing purpose I've added the tcpdf.crt file to trusted identities and it works fine.

But..I can't ask the clients to do the same. The pdf file received should be already validated when is open or at least don't display the message:  "Certification by My company is invalid". So, what crt should i use for getting a validated pdf file? I tried to use the crt available for my secured website but I'm getting the same error.

Thank you

Comment: You should purchase a certificate from one of the companies that are included in the trusted list. A certificate signed by someone else obviously cannot be trusted. https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/approved-trust-list1.html

Comment: But it's mandatory to have this certificate? I mean what if the sender sign this pdf file with his own digital signature? Let's say the pdf file is an agreement between agent and client and the agent will have it's own digital signature, there is still need for this trusted certificate?